# AuthenticationTokenProvider/Why context.SerializeTicket() and access_token not the same?

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

**Why `context.SerializeTicket()` and `access_token` not the same？**

```
public override async Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {
        //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Ticket.Identity.Name)) return;

        var clientId = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:client_id");

        var refreshTokenId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");

        var refreshToken = new RefreshToken
        {
            Id = refreshTokenId,
            ClientId = clientId,
            UserName = context.Ticket.Identity.Name,
            IssuedUtc = DateTime.Now,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30)
        };
        context.Ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = refreshToken.IssuedUtc;
        context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = refreshToken.ExpiresUtc;

        refreshToken.ProtectedTicket = context.SerializeTicket();

        await _cacheManager.SetAsync(refreshTokenId, refreshToken, TimeSpan.FromDays(10));
        context.SetToken(refreshTokenId);
    }
```

Result:

```
refreshToken.ProtectedTicket = "M2NQCH_kdzOJyHj9Sc-i_WjZtwS1Tqe3WjFXf-Laja80RUw_cOIZ9IH-Bhh3rlZx64lYxj6IUILJsBNG5FPMm7edaJqYA-qEsqYJjLTSUgSEIikeiomxcQA4qK2397HwhhzwA10QNMLFAUVscEE8MzJ4kGn_qanMP-xW3YVMycQLgGBjC5pDqBd8Q1U0nHQ5Cwe1OvWrngnq06Qe5QvZfRrMppw8MyyoliqRtPyq0UU";
```

Postman:

```
{"access_token":"jL1f5jI16pZpAmeNIvOCXe7zMEi1WT3ElOt1Tau-vfDV3iBNm6cH6oXz4XzLW2Y-2Me2Hyvl09R3vHWedlYUTiGAmFK4m75jomeqNbK2L9nnOv8-1N6iaEpB2ppT9bYLF9c77SMtmcQoLG0iBpdNu9fVObl5u5W7M5yxi6Kjq5MYdYLdzczfkaP3QA1csHdWeiuCEHf9Dw6F8XKYRpqFqUiSzFcqUW3qXcWrTF1Hfsk","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":2591999,"refresh_token":"05d7b5373b8c490fb136afe985d756ab"}
```

Answer (score 0):

- `access_token` is the token issued when the user is authenticated.
- `context.SerializeTicket()` serializes the refresh token.

> Why context. SerializeTicket ( ) and access_token not the same?

They are different because they represent different things.

**[bonus]**
`refresh_token` contains the key used to retrieve and deserialize the refresh token. This is done inside the Receive or ReceiveAsync method.